# System cannot poweroff when assigning commands' output to variables

Tags: command-line, bash

I have this pretty simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Variables
directorio=$(dirname "${0}")
distribucion=$(lsb_release -s -c)
arquitectura=$(uname -m)

echo "I am in ${directorio}, in ${distribucion} with the ${arquitectura} arch."

exit 0
```

Which actually works, it returns the following line:

```
I am in ., in xenial with the x86_64 arch.
```

So everything seems to be OK, excepting every single time I run it, the system is not able to poweroff nor reboot:

[image: Stuck System when poweroff]

It gets stuck right there -image-, and do not do anything else.

I am running an Ubuntu Mini 16.04.4 LTS x86_64, updated to the latest, without any modifications.

Comment: Why do you think the shutdown issue has anything to do with the script? That’s actually *very* unlikely – unmounting the drive mentioned in the first line rather seems to be the problem.

Comment: Just a nitpick: "${0}" should expand to script or shell name in interactive session and with `sh -c '...' whatever` to `whatever`, i.e. it's direct assignment. The fact you got `.` in script from that seems to suggest it's being sourced. Use `$PWD` as others suggest. Also try to unmount that directory manually when system is running, see if that reveals any errors

Comment: Also note that for running scripts on mounted filesystem, the filesystem itself should allow executing stuff, i.e. properly mounted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for helping find the problem, especially to the [contribution of dessert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045139/system-cannot-poweroff-when-assigning-commands-output-to-variables?#comment1704310_1045139):

> Why do you think the shutdown issue has anything to do with the script? That’s actually very unlikely – unmounting the drive mentioned in the first line rather seems to be the problem.
>   ~dessert

This kind of behavior seems to be a kind of bug in the NFS packages (`nfs-common`), so I have been testing how to reproduce this, and a way to avoid it.

To reproduce it I have used the following:

#### Host

- **KDE Neon 5.12 x86_64 (based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)** (updated and upgraded to the latest)
- `openssh-client` (version `1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4`)
- `nfs-kernel-server` (version `1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12.1`)
- `virtualbox-5.2` (version `5.2.12-122591~Ubuntu~xenial`) - *for virtualizing the guest*

#### Guest

- **Ubuntu Mini 16.04.4 LTS x86_64** (updated and upgraded to the latest) - *neither any interface nor extra package has been installed in this machine*
- `openssh-server` (version `1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4`)
- `nfs-common` (version `1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12.1`)

---

## The problem

The problem seems to be related with the NFS mounted folder inside the guest machine. This guest is prepared via `/etc/fstab` to auto-mount the host's NFS-shared folder.

Let's say:

```
# Host
/data/shared  davdriver:davdriver  777
       |
       +----  /folder1    davdriver:davdriver  777
       +----  /folder2    davdriver:davdriver  777
       +----  /script.sh  davdriver:davdriver  777  #The script mentioned in the question

# Guest
/data/nfs     davdriver:davdriver  777  #fstab: nofail,auto,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800
```

Everything at this point works perfectly fine.

---

The problem is, the machine gets somehow stuck while running a script and any poweroff-kind command (`poweroff`, `reboot`, ...) inside a NFS-mounted folder.

I have done the following tests:

#### Test 1: Running `poweroff` *INSIDE* the NFS-mounted folder

```
cd /data/nfs/folder1
poweroff
# OK
```

#### Test 2: Running a shared script and `poweroff` *INSIDE* the NFS-mounted folder

```
cd /data/nfs/
./script.sh
poweroff
# GETS STUCK ! (the snapshot in the question)
```

#### Test 3: Running a shared script and `poweroff` *OUTSIDE* the NFS-mounted folder

```
cd /data/nfs/
./script.sh
cd /data
poweroff
# OK
```

#### Test 4: Running a shared script, unmounting the NFS-mounted folder, and running the `poweroff` *INSIDE* the folder used to mount NFS.

```
cd /data/nfs/
./script.sh
cd /data
umount ./nfs
cd ./nfs
poweroff
# OK
```

## The solution

After running the script, the NFS service seems to be busy with any background process, and only by running the `poweroff` command outside the NFS-mounted folder seems to help the system unmounting it and allowing it to shutdown.

It is also possible to unmount it first and accessing the root folder that have been mounted, this scenario seems to not affect and the system will also poweroff.